# which loss function is better for multi-classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, loss-functions

I training the multilabel classifier using the RBF network. I want to choose between different loss functions. I looked at a bunch of documentation about the different loss functions but can't get an intuitive sense of when to use one over the others. I can't decide between hinge loss, correntropy (c-loss) and SLS loss functions. also I can't find any good document to explain SLS and ASLS loss function.

here is the picture of these loss functions which I find in [this](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-asymmetric-stagewise-least-square-loss-function-Xu-Hu/73250fcf51a683bb412a5387bfb2f12eb31687ab) paper

[image: image one]

[image]

considering that I use passive aggrasive method for updating weights which one of these functions is better?
I realize this is a short question, but not quite sure what other information to provide.